# How to set ArrayAdapter inside Postexecute

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying to set an arrayadapter inside Postexecute class,to show a list of suggestions(values of array array_topic_names) while user try to enter some text in edittext.

Although I am receiving data from database,and have successfully stored it in array array_topic_names,but after I set an array adapter it shows NULL.

```
protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {

                int success = 0;
                String message = "";

                Log.d("post exec", "starting");

                Log.d("json", json.toString());

                if (pDialog != null && pDialog.isShowing()) {
                    pDialog.dismiss();
                }

                if (json != null) {
                    {
                        Log.d("json", "not null");

                        String array_topic_names[]=new String[100];
                        JSONArray data = null;
                        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter2;
                        try {
                            data = json.getJSONArray("details");

                            Log.d("JSON result",json.toString());
                            for(int i=0;i<7;i++) {
                                JSONObject obj = data.getJSONObject(i);
                                Log.d("obj_value", obj.toString());
                                array_topic_names[i]=obj.toString().substring(15).replace("}","").replace("\"","");
                                Log.d("array_topic_names", array_topic_names[i]);

                                adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, array_topic_names);

                                edttxt1.setThreshold(1);
                                //Set adapter to AutoCompleteTextView
                                edttxt1.setAdapter(adapter2);
                                edttxt1.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
                                edttxt1.setOnItemClickListener(this);



                            }
                            //adapter2.notifyDataSetChanged();




                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

                }

            }
```

LOGCAT

```
2 22230-22230/com.example.somya.client_feedback_application D/post exec: starting
06-29 18:21:04.752 22230-22230/com.example.somya.client_feedback_application D/json: {"details":[{"topic_name":"abc"},{"topic_name":"xyz"},{"topic_name":"bbb"},{"topic_name":"ccc"},{"topic_name":"1a"},{"topic_name":"2b"},{"topic_name":"3c"}]}
06-29 18:21:04.752 22230-22230/com.example.somya.client_feedback_application D/json: not null
06-29 18:21:04.752 22230-22230/com.example.somya.client_feedback_application D/JSON result: {"details":[{"topic_name":"abc"},{"topic_name":"xyz"},{"topic_name":"bbb"},{"topic_name":"ccc"},{"topic_name":"1a"},{"topic_name":"2b"},{"topic_name":"3c"}]}
06-29 18:21:04.752 22230-22230/com.example.somya.client_feedback_application D/obj_value: {"topic_name":"abc"}
06-29 18:21:04.752 22230-22230/com.example.somya.client_feedback_application D/array_topic_names: abc
06-29 18:21:04.752 22230-22230/com.example.somya.client_feedback_application D/obj_value: {"topic_name":"xyz"}
06-29 18:21:04.752 22230-22230/com.example.somya.client_feedback_application D/array_topic_names: xyz
06-29 18:21:04.752 22230-22230/com.example.somya.client_feedback_application D/obj_value: {"topic_name":"bbb"}
06-29 18:21:04.752 22230-22230/com.example.somya.client_feedback_application D/array_topic_names: bbb
06-29 18:21:04.752 22230-22230/com.example.somya.client_feedback_application D/obj_value: {"topic_name":"ccc"}
06-29 18:21:04.752 22230-22230/com.example.somya.client_feedback_application D/array_topic_names: ccc
06-29 18:21:04.752 22230-22230/com.example.somya.client_feedback_application D/obj_value: {"topic_name":"1a"}
06-29 18:21:04.752 22230-22230/com.example.somya.client_feedback_application D/array_topic_names: 1a
06-29 18:21:04.752 22230-22230/com.example.somya.client_feedback_application D/obj_value: {"topic_name":"2b"}
06-29 18:21:04.752 22230-22230/com.example.somya.client_feedback_application D/array_topic_names: 2b
06-29 18:21:04.752 22230-22230/com.example.somya.client_feedback_application D/obj_value: {"topic_name":"3c"}
06-29 18:21:04.752 22230-22230/com.example.somya.client_feedback_application D/array_topic_names: 3c
06-29 18:21:04.943 720-747/system_process I/ActivityManager: Displayed com.example.somya.client_feedback_application/.create_form: +821ms
06-29 18:21:27.312 22230-22794/com.example.somya.client_feedback_application W/Filter: An exception occured during performFiltering()!
                                                                                       java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference
                                                                                           at android.widget.ArrayAdapter$ArrayFilter.performFiltering(ArrayAdapter.java:480)
                                                                                           at android.widget.Filter$RequestHandler.handleMessage(Filter.java:234)
                                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                                           at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

Comment: Why are you doing substring when you can just access the value using `obj.getString("topic_name")`?

Comment: @Apoorv Oops okay .Thanks for it.Can you also tell me the solution to my above problem

Comment: Most likely because you are initializing `array_topic_names` to a static size 100. Instead it should be the same size as `data.length()`

Comment: @Apporv It worked.Thanks